# Why analogize « balafre » to human lips?

Tags: étymologie

> (E. Deschamps, ibid.) avec *balèvre** p[ar]. anal[ogie]. entre les lèvres d'une plaie et les lèvres du visage.

I'm flabbergasted by [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balafre) above, and Wiktionary below.  What exactly is this "analogie entre les lèvres d’une plaie et les lèvres du visage"? Are these two quotations alleging that scar tissues and gashes look like *labia oris*? If so, then I fail to behold this analogy!

> #### [Étymologie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/balafre)
>
> *(1505)* Croisement de *[balèvre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bal%C3%A8vre#fr)* par analogie entre les [lèvres](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A8vre) d’une plaie et les lèvres du visage, et de l’ancien français *[laffru](https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=laffru&action=edit&redlink=1)*, *[lavru](https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=lavru&action=edit&redlink=1)* (« [lippu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lippu) »).

I have beholden pictures of scars near lips. They don't look human lips to me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do a google image search for [*balafre*](https://marquisesdesange.skyrock.com/200055391-A-la-vue-de-son-epoux-affreusement-balafre-et-boiteux.html) ? Do you see the analogy ?

Comment: @XouDo Yes, but no. I still do not see the analogy!

Comment: *balafre* does not exactly mean scar. A scar in french is *cicatrice*. A *balafre* is specifically a long (and possibly deep) wound on the face, or the resulting scar of it. When the wound is still open, the two sides are similar to two lips around a "mouth" (in the sens of edge or border).

Comment: The upper picture scar is kind of smiling, isn't it? The edges are called lips when the wound is open, not that much after healing.

Answer (score 1):

What English calls the edges of a scar/wound, French calls the lips of it.

> *On appelle figurativement les bords d’une playe, Les levres d’une playe.*
> Dictionnaire de l'Académie, 1<sup>ère</sup> édition, 1694

The similarity between a mouth and its lips and a scar and its edges is obvious enough for the figurative meaning to be established since the Middle Ages.

[image]
<sub>[LOUISE HAYWOOD-SCHIEFER](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/uk/beauty-hair/makeup/how-to/a30677/halloween-how-to-stitched-mouth-makeup/)</sub>

Comment: "The similarity between a mouth and its lips and a scar and its edges is obvious enough". Can you please try to persuade me? The similarity is not obvious to me!

Comment: @user In  English the "edges" of a scar are also called [the lips](https://chestofbooks.com/health/wounds/Infected-Wound-Treatment/II-Technique-Of-Wound-Closing.html), the analogy is not particular to French. *Lippen einer Wunde* in German (*Lippen* →the lips), *labios de una herida* in Spanish (*los labios* →the lips).

Answer (score 1):

"Lèvre", in French, comes from *labrum*, Latin.

In Latin, *labrum* (or *labium*, more popular) has both meanings of "lips" and of "edge" (and also "big jar", but this is a different word). Source: Gaffiot, Dictionnaire abrégé latin-français.

In English also, "lip" can be used figuratively. Google search has results for "lips of a wound", e.g.:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conglutinant